# Trouble setting up coursebuilder analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I've been setting up a course for my class on coursebuilder and I've been having trouble setting up coursebuilder analytics. I followed the steps that they [provided](https://www.google.com/edu/openonline/course-builder/docs/1.10/analyze-data/course-builder-analytics.html) in setting it up but most of my data results are stuck at updating.

It would be really helpful if anyone who has used coursebuilder could help me out here.

Thanks in advance.